# i have multiple dynamic textboxes in my form .I want to retrieve values of all textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<label for="firstName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">'.$r['1'].'</label>

<div class="col-lg-5">
    <input type=text name="text_quest" class="form-control">
</div>
```

This whole code is inside while loop. I want to retrieve all values of textboxes which are being created in form.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class other then `form-control` to all textboxes because this class is used by bootstrap and get the value in jquery like:

```
<input type=text name="text_quest" class="form-control userInput">

$('.userInput').each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).val() );
});
```

this will print value of each textbox in console. You can push the values in an array also and use that array.

Answer (score 0):

Using Request form you can get textbox values in your post Method like this.

string[] textboxesvalue = Request.Form.GetValues("text_quest");

Answer (score 0):

`var textboxElements = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")` will return an array-like object of all your textbox elements. You can iterate that object properties to access every textbox value like following:

```
[].forEach.call(textboxElements, function (textboxElement) {
  console.log(textboxElement.value);
});
```